# video cuttur output video is 0 byte

Tags: c#, video

This is my code for video cuttur. file is saving but its size is only 0 byte and when open nothing is play. I'm using ***Video Edit Gold SDK ActiveX*** tool.

```
 string strInputVideo = null;
            strInputVideo = "C:/Users/Ramisha Farrukh/Downloads/Fusion Fire Chicken Recipe By Food Fusion.wmv";
            axVideoEdit1.OutputType = VIDEOEDITLib.MYOUTPUT.VCD_PAL;
            axVideoEdit1.VideoSampleSize = 34;
            axVideoEdit1.InitControl();
            axVideoEdit1.AddVideo(strInputVideo, 5, 10, 0);
            axVideoEdit1.AddAudio(strInputVideo, 5, 10);
            axVideoEdit1.Save("E:/testvideo.wmv");
```

Comment: You haven't specified an actual video file have you?

Comment: @AndrewHarris yes I forget. but after putting when again run the program same output